# Possible to use AngularUI jQuery PassThrough for the WayPoints plugin?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-waypoints

I was going to try and write a directive for this jQuery WayPoints plugin http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#documentation

But then discovered AngularUI with jQuery Passthrough which claims to support 75% of jQuery plugins.
http://angular-ui.github.com/

Can someone please write an example of how I could use this jQuery WayPoints plugin in my AngularJS app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloopy/Mx4Hb/) is a fiddle that appears to work using the AngularUI jQuery Passthrough with Waypoints. The main things to note are:

1) Include the angular-ui.js script (which is a pretty awesome AngularJS companion!)

2) Add `['ui']` in the requires parameter when registering the module

```
angular.module('waypoints', ['ui']);
```

3) Add a function in your controller that you want to call when the waypoint is hit

```
function WaypointsController($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(){
        alert('you have scrolled');
    }
}​
```

4) Set up the `ui-jq` directive passing the function into the `ui-options`

```
<div ui-jq="waypoint" ui-options="test">
```

Comment: How do you add direction/options into that? ;-)

Comment: Updated fiddle for chrome (chrome refusing to execute script - XSS) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mx4Hb/18/)

Answer (score 4):

To answer Marco's question:

3) Add a function in your controller that you want to call when the waypoint is hit

```
function WaypointsController($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(direction){
        alert('you have scrolled ' + direction);
    };
    $scope.optionsObj = {
        offset: 50
        //additional options
    };
}​
```

4) Set up the `ui-jq` directive passing the function into the `ui-options`

```
<div ui-jq="waypoint" ui-options="test, optionsObj">
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mx4Hb/19/) is a fiddle showing this in action